# How to Format Numbers to Control the Exponential Part

Tags: r

Consider the following code,

```
x <- 1000 * 1.23
x
```

which returns 1230

```
format(x, scientific=TRUE)
```

which returns 1.23e+03

But if I have

```
y <- 10000 * 1.23
y
```

which returns 12300

```
format(y, scientific=TRUE)
```

returns 1.23e+04

How can I format the y value so that I can control the exponent?

I want y to be expressed as 12.3e+03?

Comment: Just a slight modification. format() returns a character value (in quotes), not a numeric value as you claimed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R, and most programming languages, only support [*normalized* scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Normalized_notation). Of course, you could always roll your own:

```
scientific <- function(x, exponent = 3) { 
  opts <- options(scipen = 20); on.exit(options(opts))
  sprintf("%se%s%02d", x / 10^exponent, if (exponent >= 0) '+' else '-', abs(exponent)) 
}
```

## Examples

```
cat(scientific(12300, 4)) # 1.23e+04
cat(scientific(12300, 3)) # 12.3e+03
```

## Truncating larger number

When numbers are very large, it could be handy to remove some numbers at the end. You could the `format` function with the specified number of digits like this:

```
scientific <- function(x, exponent = 3, digits = 3) { 
  opts <- options(scipen = 20); on.exit(options(opts))
  tmp = format(x = x / 10^exponent, digits = digits)
  sprintf("%se%s%02d", tmp, if (exponent >= 0) '+' else '-', abs(exponent)) 
}
```

## Example

```
scientific(12345678987654321234567865432,exponent = 25,digits = 6) # "1234.57e+25"
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert.  I'm working in 'kilo' units (as it happens, kcal for activation energies), so changing 10^4 to 10^3 is simpler to read.  I would imagine other situations where your function could be used to take into account 10^6, 10^9, etc etc so it's worth more than one tick!